# cannot run service jboss eap 6.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I want run the service jboss eap and deploy the war but I found an error. error below:

```
C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\bin>standalone.bat 
Calling "C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\standalone.conf.bat" 
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java"
```

JBoss Bootstrap Environment :
%JBOSS_HOME% :

```
"C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4"
```

JAVA:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java"
```

JAVA_OPTS:

```
"-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCL ogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnlo ading -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:Max PermSize=512M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Djboss.modules.policy-permission s=true  -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"


Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0 Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration/logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration\logging.properties (The system cannot find the path specified))
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018701: Configuration directory does not exist:
C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:387)
   at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:265)
   at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:93)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
   at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:473) Press any key to continue . . .
```

How to fix this problem? and how to deploy the war after this step solved? for information, I don't have file logging.properties in path "C:\Users\c76266\Desktop\dev-tools-java\portable-dev-tools\jboss-eap-6.4\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration\" and how to change the path? maybe that's the root problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The logging.properties file is for the Bootup Logging. [12.1.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-The_Logging_Subsystem.html)
This file will be generated and overwritten if the logging subsystem has been defined in the standalone.xml. Example:

```
loggers=sun.rmi,org.jboss.as.config,com.arjuna

logger.level=ALL
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=COLOR-PATTERN
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush,target,enabled
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=YOUR_JBOSS_HOME\\standalone\\log\\server.log

formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n
```

Please create the file under the right folder. How did you configure your logging in the standalone.xml?